# CTRL F function and referencing the found cells entire row

Tags: excel, vba

With regards to excel VBA, how would I use the ctrl F function to find a specific cell and then copy that cells entire row to the bottom of the data set and then delete the row I initially searched for?

To be more specific the word I am searching for will always be there, will always be in the same column (Columns adjacent to this cell will contain other information linked to this word as to why I need to copy the entire row) and will only be in the data set once however the row it will be in will change as will the amount of rows in the data set.

What I would like to do is to copy and paste this entire row to the bottom of the data set and delete the entry from it's original position.

I have looked into the ctrl F function but am struggling to then refer back to the found cell and paste it at the bottom of the data.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Find`, if successful, returns a `Range` so you would just copy the `.EntireRow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working on `Sheet1` and the value you are searching for is in `Column A`. You will need to update all of the above references to fit your actual data.

You may also want to amend the criteria for the `Range.Find` method to suit your needs *(for instance partial match vs exact match)*. More info on how to do that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

---

```
Sub Shelter_In_Place()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update

Dim lr As Long, Found As Range, Target As String

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Target = "Some Word"
Set Found = ws.Range("A1:A" & lr).Find(Target)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    Found.EntireRow.Copy
    ws.Range("A" & lr + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Found.EntireRow.Delete
Else
    MsgBox Target & " not found in Column"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for my very late comment, I did however end up using your answer and it worked like a charm, got in there just before my question was closed. You are a godsend :D